# Socket Programming.connecting multiple clients to server

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a socket program.Consider that there are 4 clients(Client 'A' Client 'B' Client 'C'  Client 'D'). I need all these clients to be connected to a single server. After this, if Client 'A' sends a message to the Server , the Server should send the same message back to all the remaining Clients(Client 'B' Client 'C'  Client 'D').

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but one option is that you can use threading to connect multiple clients to a server. [Here](http://www.ase.md/~aursu/ClientServerThreads.html) you have some documentation and examples about this matter.

Comment: Well, no, he won't 'have to use threading'. That's one of several alternatives.

Comment: You're right @EJP, I think for a beginner this will be the most easiest.

Comment: Please send me a program.

Comment: @ahbay sachu, check the link out. There are also code samples. If you want to have complete program, you will have to read through it and apply the code. [http://www.ase.md/~aursu/ClientServerThreads.html]